# I can't modify an array in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make some modifications to a data array returned from a mongoose/MongDB query.  However, I can't seem to make any changes to the array.  Am I missing something obvious here?

```
function stdSend(err, data, res){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.send(err);
  }else{
    console.log('rows returned: ' + data.length);
    for(var rep=0;rep<data.length;rep++){
      var foo = new Date(data[rep].timestamp);   
      console.log(Object.isFrozen(data[rep]));    <- false
      console.log(Object.isSealed(data[rep]));    <- false
      data[rep].test = 'test';                    <- test not added to data[rep]
      data[rep].timestamp = foo;                  <- timestamp not modified
      console.dir(data[rep]);
    }
    //console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
  }
}
```

stdSend is being called from the Mongoose .exec function as the callback.  The callback works fine and the data goes to the browser after I feed it to res.send in Express.  However, I wanted to do some quick bug-testing by converting the data[].timestamp values into standard datetime values before sending it out.

However, everything I've tried to change the values of data have failed.  The data[rep].test = 'test' fails to add a test property to data and the attempt to modify timestamp also fails.  Both isFrozen and isSealed return false.

Any ideas what's going on here?

**Edit:**
I think there's some confusion about what I'm asking here.  I am *not* writing the data to the database.  This is an object array returned from the DB query that I am trying to modify.  The returned object is below:

```
[ { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1380154343818,
    funding: 42,
    subs: 3500 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1380240748329,
    funding: 42,
    subs: 3520 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1380327152521,
    funding: 42,
    subs: 3554 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1380413558026,
    funding: 43,
    subs: 3579 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1380585807946,
    funding: 43,
    subs: 3638 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1384300959056,
    funding: 52,
    subs: 5 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1384560752617,
    funding: 53,
    subs: 5 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1384646717448,
    funding: 53,
    subs: 5 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1384819280960,
    funding: 53,
    subs: 5 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1385251243369,
    funding: 53,
    subs: 5753 },
  { name: 'scishow',
    timestamp: 1385338257810,
    funding: 53,
    subs: 5779 } ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `data` is the result of a Mongoose query, it's not an array of plain JS objects, but an array of document instances. They may *look* like proper JS objects, but you can't treat them as such.

You need to convert those documents to proper JS objects before you can change them:

```
for (var rep = 0; rep < data.length; rep++) {
  var doc = data[rep].toObject();
  var foo = new Date(doc.timestamp);
  doc.test = 'test';
  doc.timestamp = foo;
  console.dir(doc);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add `{ strict: false }` to your schema (as @HenryLeu suggested) and use `.set()` on the documents to add properties:

```
data[rep].set('test', 'test');
```

Or without changing your schema:

```
data[rep].set('test', 'test', { strict: false });
```

Comment: damn, I spent like literally three hours debugging this, `.set()` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your mongoose schema definition code. try to use option `strict: false` to enable setting and getting undefined schema fields. by default, `strict` is `true`.

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({name: String, ...}, { strict: false});
```

Please, reference [mongoose docs about strict option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict).

Comment: That doesn't help. I'm not writing to the DB.  I'm modifying the data returned from the query before sending it out to the Express response object.

Answer (score 0):

@robertklep answer was helpful to me but if you are trying to render the documents with EJS, the key:value you just appended using `.set()` will return `undefined` because EJS receives the mongo record as the document and not as a JSON.

So, if you are not looking for a Mongo document but just the JSON, you can use [`.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) when used with `.exec()` will return a JSON object instead of Mongo documents.

```
YOUR_MODEL.find()
.lean().exec((err, data) => {
  if(err) throw err;

  //Assuming data will return something like [{myKey: val}, {myKey: val}]

  data.forEach((obj, idx) => {
    data[idx].myKey = 'alterValue';
  });
});
```